# Regex - regular expression match string exactly

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using regular expression in adobe javascript to find a string of words in a drawing title block. Starting with a number (1) then a date then a varying number of words and 4 sets of initials

```
var re = new RegExp(1+"\\s\\d{1,2}\\.\\d{1,2}\\.\\d{2,4}\\s\\w+(?:\\s+\\w+){1,9}\\s([A-Z]{2,7})\\s([A-Z]{2,7})\\s([A-Z]{2,7})\\s([A-Z]{2,7})");
```

The drawing title block example has the following:

1 20.09.16 CHANGES FOR THIS TESTING SB SB BW CR

0 29.07.16 APPROVED FOR CONSTRUCTION MM SB BW GM

The regular expression result is

FOR CONSTRUCTION MM SB BW GM 1 20.09.16 CHANGES FOR THIS TESTING SB SB

I need the regular expression to be

1 20.09.16 CHAINAGES FOR THIS TEST SB SB BW CR

Can anyone advise how to find the exact match starting with the 1 and not random text as shown in the result.

Many thanks for any assistance.

Note:  modified regex below works

```
var re = new RegExp(/^1\s\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{2,4}\s\w+(?:\s+\w+){1,10}\s([A-Z]{2,2})\s([A-Z]{2,2})\s([A-Z]{2,2})\s([A-Z]{2,2})$/g);
```

I need to replace the 1 at the beginning of the regex from text to a variable.

The regex starts with ^ first then the javascript variable then the regex

```
var re = new RegExp("//^"+firstWord+"\\s\\d{1,2}\\.\\d{1,2}\\.\\d{2,4}\\s\\w+(?:\\s+\\w+){1,9}\\s([A-Z]{2,4})\\s([A-Z]{2,4})\\s([A-Z]{2,4})\\s([A-Z]{2,4})$//g");
```

The regex is not working, can anyone advise how to combine java variable with regex?

Comment: I Don't understand why the results are "out of order" without knowing how the drawing title block is stored.  But if you want to match something that starts with a `1`, you need to put a `1` at the beginning of your regex.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show how you are using the regex. Also, the result that you show includes characters ("CS") that weren't in your sample input at all, which doesn't make any sense - please double-check your sample input and result.

Comment: I have edited the question with the revised regex which is now working, need help with a regex split at an underscore - hope you can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why your result turned out like that, but if you just do

```
var str = '1 20.09.16 CHANGES FOR THIS TESTING SB SB BW CR 0 29.07.16 APPROVED FOR CONSTRUCTION MM SB BW GM'

var result = str.match(/1\s\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{2,4}\s\w+(?:\s+\w+){1,9}\s([A-Z]{2,7})\s([A-Z]{2,7})\s([A-Z]{2,7})\s([A-Z]{2,7})/g)
```

This return

`[ '1 20.09.16 CHANGES FOR THIS TESTING SB SB BW CR' ]`

To get the string, you just need to do `result[0]`

Comment: Modified your regex var re = new RegExp(/^1\s\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{2,4}\s\w+(?:\s+\w+){1,9}\s([A-Z]{2,7})\s([A-Z]{2,7})\s([A-Z]{2,7})\s([A-Z]{2,7})$/g); Result is: 1 20.09.16 CHANGES FOR THIS TEST SB SB missing last two sets of initials, any ideas as to why please?

Comment: `$` means end of line, not end of string, if you have multiline string, it may not match, try `\z` instead.

Comment: Thanks for help have edited question with correct regex result which is working, need help with a regex split at underscore - hope you can help.

Comment: Changed the regex in the question, need help to combine java variable with regex, please advise help?